# Changing default Django date format from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: django, date

I'm struggling to correctly set my date format in my local Django app. Everything saves into the database as `yyyy-mm-dd` and I've been on this site all night and none of the examples work and I'm out of ideas

I've tried setting default `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` in `settings.py` and various date parameters in my `form.py`

i.e

```
date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y']) ,
```

and

```
date = forms.DateField(
    widget=forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'),
    input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y', )
    )
```

my date value in my model is

```
date = models.DateField()
```

My form data is

```
class MacroForm(forms.ModelForm):

    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y')), input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y',))

    class Meta:
      model = Macro
      fields = ('country', 'date', 'value','comment')
```

my `settings.py` has the following

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'eng'

TIME_ZONE = 'GMT'

USE_I18N = False

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    ("%d/%m/%Y"),
]
```

Unfortunately everything I try is going in the database as `yyyy-mm-dd`. I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a pointer to what I'm doing wrong. I would have liked to set it somehow in the model but I don't think that's possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your database will always store the datetime values in a standardised format. The custom formats are only for humans to enter/interpret dates more easily.

Comment: Hope it is storing as a standard datetime object. Share your model too

Comment: Ah ok, maybe thats the point I'm missing, I'm pulling the data straight from an sqlite3 database so maybe I just need to convert it before its rendered.

Here is my model (sorry about the formatting)
'''
class Macro(models.Model):
        country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,      null=True)
        date = models.DateField()
        value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
        comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

Comment: One thing, below is some code from my view, before I save my form instance  I put a print line in to print the date and its already in YYYY-MM-DD format before going to the database?
'''
def create_macro(request):
    model = Macro
    form = MacroForm()

    if 'single_macro' in request.POST:
        print("Single")
        form = MacroForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, )
        
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            print(instance.date)